# Polymorphic values in Java

Tags: java, haskell, types, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I'm studying Haskell and came across *polymorphic values*. These are the values that have different type depending on the context. For example, `Nothing` has type `Maybe a` or `[]` has type `[a]`. So `[]` is list of anything you want and you can use it everywhere any list is expected.

I struggle to find a similar thing in Java, apart from "billion-dollar mistake" `null`, which is basically of any type. May be generics with unbounded wildcard is similar, but again, I can't think of an example.

Is there something similar in Java?

Comment: Given `null` is one of the most used and re-used techniques in many languages, a billion-dollar mistake is likely to be sensationalised, some people struggle with it esp beginners but I don't see it as a problem.  An `Object` reference can point to any object type.

Comment: I think generics is the thing that comes the closest but it's still a long way away. Overall though, I don't think it's a very productive idea to try to map ideas one-to-one from two such different paradigms. For example, a kind of polymorphism is built into inheritance, a variable of type `Object` can hold any value, but it doesn't work the other way around. Does that stunted parallel help you understand either Haskell or Java better? I doubt it.

Comment: Polymorphic values values work through _parametric polymorphism_, which Java doesn't have. So, this is basically impossible in the same way inheritance is “impossible” in C: you can certainly emulate it in several ways ([obviously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)), but whether that's sensible or you wouldn't be off better with something more idiomatic is doubtful.

Comment: Generics are a form of parametric polymorphism. This is more a matter of syntax and type inference.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/eallik/learning-haskell-runtime-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more a comment than an actual answer, but I require more space.

While the type systems of Java and Haskell are quite apart, some similarities can be found in certain features. Here are a few examples: just keep in mind that there is no perfect correspondence between the related constructs shown below.

Polymorphic functions (as in FP, not OOP polymorphism):

```hs
fst :: forall a b. (a, b) -> a
fst (x,y) = x
```

```java
<A,B> A fst(A a, B b) {
    return a;
}
```

Note that polymorphic non-function values can not be translated as easily. Even in Haskell, values such as `3 :: Num a => a` are functions in disguise. Further, `[] :: [a]` and `Nothing :: Maybe a` are also treated as functions, taking a "type" parameter in some stages of compilation -- albeit, IIRC at runtime these parameter disappear.

Type arguments:

```hs
data T a = T a Int a
```

```java
class T<A> {
    A x;
    int n;
    A y;

    T(A x, int n, A y) {
        this.x = x; this.n = n; this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Algebraic data types (e.g. `data` with many constructors): these are not directly available in Java. Some other JVM languages, like Scala, have ADT supported directly in the language, as well as pattern patching and non-exhaustiveness warnings. In Java, you can use the so-called [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to simulate ADT value elimination, which is a basic form of pattern matching.

Comment: The problem with your first example is that `fst` is not a value in Java. A method reference like `YourClass::fst` is, but it isn't polymorphic: it'll only work if it infers `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2):

A polymorphic value like `[]` can only be represented as a method in Java. In fact, this method already exists in the `Arrays` class and is called `asList`. And because of Java's type inference, you don't even need to provide type arguments:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myList = Arrays.asList();
    }
}
```

If you ignore all the noise, `[]` ≡ `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: Good answer. But I guess it's better to use `Collections.emptyList()` since `Arrays.asList()` allocates a new object each time you invoke it. However, `Collections.emptyList()` is immutable.