# Function with generic type as member variable

Tags: java, generics

I have a function which maps a `class` object to an instance of this class.
Basically:

```
 Function<Class<T>, T> fun;
```

I can define this function within a method but when trying to put this in a member variable, the compiler complains because the type `T` is unknown.

So, `T` is not specific to the enclosing object. It might differ from call to call. What is the correct syntax to define such a function on class level?

****EDIT****

I would like to clarify. I have class `A`

```
public class A {
  public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {...}
}
```

Now, I want to hand a pointer to that function to class `B` like this:

```
public class B {
  <T> Function<Class<T>, T> fun;
  
  public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return fun.apply(clazz);
  }
}
```

However, the Syntax for `<T> Function<Class<T>, T> fun` is incorrect. Is there a way to keep the information, that fun will always retain the type `T`?

My current solution is

```
public class B {
  Function<Class<?>, ?> fun;

  public <T> void setFun(Function<Class<T>, T> fun) {
    this.fun = fun;
  }

  public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) fun.apply(clazz);
  }
}
```

This works (and is obviously correct via invariant) but kinda ugly because of the required cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java (and JVM) values are not polymorphic, methods are.

So correct is to define it with a method

```
<T> Function<Class<T>, T> fun();
```

[Polymorphic values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886128/polymorphic-values-in-java)

---

Regarding **EDIT**.

> Now, I want to hand a pointer to that function to class `B` like this:
>
> ```
> public class B {
>   <T> Function<Class<T>, T> fun;
>  
>   public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
>     return fun.apply(clazz);
>   }
> }
> ```

Once again, a value (including a field) can't be polymorphic, method can.

- So you can make `fun` a method

  ```
   public abstract class B {
      abstract <T> Function<Class<T>, T> fun();

      public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
          return this.<T>fun().apply(clazz);
      }
   }
  ```

  You can't write setter like `setFun`. Its signature should be something like

  ```
   public void setFun(<T> Function<Class<T>, T> fun); // pseudocode
  ```

  rather than

  ```
   public <T> void setFun(Function<Class<T>, T> fun);
  ```

  `<T> Function<Class<T>, T>` is called rank-N type and it's absent in Java

  [What is the purpose of Rank2Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types)

  https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types
- Alternatively, you can wrap polymorphic `fun` with a class (interface)

  ```
  public interface PolyFunction {
      <T> T apply(Class<T> clazz);
  }

  public class B {
      PolyFunction fun;

      public void setFun(PolyFunction fun) {
          this.fun = fun;
      }

      public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
          return fun.apply(clazz);
      }
  }
  ```

  `PolyFunction` looks like your `A` so maybe you want

  ```
  public class B {
      A a;

      public void setA(A a) {
          this.a = a;
      }

      public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
          return a.get(clazz);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: The only value this can return is `null`, because `Test<?> t = new Test<>(); Function<Class<String>, String> strFn = t.fun(); Function<Class<Integer>, Integer> intFn = t.fun();` are both legal.

Comment: @AndyTurner It's a function so I guess you're wrong (about `null` being the only option). For example `<T> Function<Class<T>, T> fun() { return (Class<T> cls) -> { T t = null; try { t = cls.newInstance(); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); } return t; }; }`.

Comment: I guess I am, then!